# Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-work EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x001a00015ed6be80

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

Thanks in advance if anybody can resolve my problem.
I am using `NSURLSession` API for network calls.

App is crashing on iOS9+ version.
See below crash thread:

> 1. Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-work 0  libobjc.A.dylib
>      0x1812f5b88 objc_msgSend + 8 1  CFNetwork
>      0x1822d6d4c  + 56 2  CFNetwork
>      0x18235b718  + 40 3  libdispatch.dylib
>      0x1816c94bc  + 24 4  libdispatch.dylib
>      0x1816c947c  + 16 5  libdispatch.dylib
>      0x1816d54c0  + 864 6  libdispatch.dylib
>      0x1816ccf80  + 464 7  libdispatch.dylib
>      0x1816d7390  + 728 8  libdispatch.dylib
>      0x1816d70b0  + 112 9  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>      0x1818e1470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092 10 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>      0x1818e1020 start_wqthread + 4

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint to get more meaningful information.

Comment: Note : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371536/nsurlsession-causing-exc-bad-access