# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using dispatch_async

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, exc-bad-access, dispatch, dispatch-async

We have recently revised our threading mechanism in favour of using `dispatch_async`'s in most places (after doing a lot of reading about NSOperation vs dispatch_async)*. Then our code started crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in various parts of the code, always on the `dispatch_async(queue,...)` part, with no clear pattern. Usually happening after 20 minutes - 2 hours.

Our `dispatch_async` blocks were used to notify listeners, looked as follows:

```html
NSMutableSet *_listeners; // Initialised elsewhere and filled with interested listeners
void(^block)(id listener); // Block to execute

@synchronized(_listeners) {
  for (id listener in _listeners) {
    dispatch_async_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0); // We used different queues for different listeners, but showing only one type of queue here for brevity
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{ // CRASHING LINE
      block(listener);
    });
  }
}
```

y common symptoms were:

- Happens on iOS10, never happens on iOS8
- Happen during debugging but never reported on production

(This is a self-answered question)

*We liked the simplicity of `dispatch_async`, didn't need the blocking / dependency features of `NSOperationQueue`'s and we will be moving to C++ soon so wanted to stay low level.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you are doing inside your `dispatch_async`?

Comment: @Oskar added code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After days of debugging, ensuring our thread objects were strongly retained, and trying various weak-strong combinations and thorough profiling using Instruments, we have come to the conclusion that **this is an Apple bug** (as also [reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371536/nsurlsession-causing-exc-bad-access/40536997#40536997)) that only appears on recent iOS versions (iOS10 for us, but I reckon it will be present from the version when `libBacktraceRecording.dylib` started appearing).

Symptoms of:

- Not reproducible on iOS8.x
- Only happens when in debugging mode
- EXC_BAD_ACCESS in random parts of the code, without any pattern

might indicate this.

Hope this is useful for others!

Comment: This is very useful to me, thank you. Pulling out my hair trying to figure out what's going on, good to know that it's not my code that's broken.